# On to the Caribbean Islands!

Tags: riddle, rebus, cryptic-clues, metapuzzles

This is a meta-puzzle. I will only confirm the answers to the sub-puzzles.

1. **Clues to words**

1.Unending approval for males in a country (5)
2.Nobleman’s “Yes” for administrative region(6)
3.The passageway is a decoy(5)
4.Desert in land of Arab and one(7)
5.Oddly engrave for say, Ironman? (7)

2. **A Riddle best told softly.**

With the Shrew his personal pet,
To faintly speak is his best bet.

“Phew Sirs”, in disgust, were his words
We could hear the murmurs of the birds.

Lots of rumours were now heard,
He only feebly mumbles, “absurd”!

This is your last hint.
Shout is what he didn’t.

3. **WORDSEARCH(Or is it to search for something else?)**
   [image]
4. **Time for a Replacement?**

Cut the sound of horse’s hoofs (4)
The Skill to do a deed (3)
Group of two colored (4)
Girlfriend’s information (4)
Treaty requires some huff and puff (4)

5. **REBUS**

[image]

Note: You might have to unscramble the letters that you get to get the final answer.

Comment: Is that a "Do Not enter" sign in the Rebus clue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### 1. Clues to Words

> `YE(-s) + MEN`
>  `COUNT+Y`
>  `A+LURE` *(archaic word for "hallway" - thanks, ffao!)
>  `_ABANDON_`
>  `AVENGER*`
>
>  Reading down the diagonal of the answer (first letter of first word, second letter of second...) gives **YOUNG**.

### 2. A Riddle Best Told Softly

> **WHISPERS** *([solved by Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/58238/11876))*

### 3. WORDSEARCH (Or is it to search for something else?)

> [image]
>  This spells the word "**TWINS**".

### 4. Time for a replacement?

> `CLIP / CLOP`
>  `ART  / ACT` 
>  `DYAD / DYED`
>  `DATE / DATA`
>  `PACT / PANT`
>  After replacement, new letters spell **OCEAN**.

### 5. Rebus

> **ROULETTE** *([solved by athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/58242/11876))*

## Meta

> Each of these words can be preceded by a nationality to form a common two-word phrase:
>  1. Young Turk *(exception to the rule)*
>  2. Chinese Whispers
>  3. Siamese Twins
>  4. Indian Ocean
>  5. Russian Roulette
>
>  The $n$th letters of the answers anagram to HAITI, the "island in the Caribbean" that the title asks for.

Comment: Don't mess the ordering in which it is given in the puzzle.

Answer (score 6):

#### Partial Answer...

**2. A Riddle best told softly.**

> **Whispers**

Reasoning:

> Most the lines contain descriptions of whispers/whispering, but additionally the first and third lines contain the word hidden:
>  With the Shre**w his pers**onal pet,  - *hidden word*
>  “**Phew Sirs**”, in disgust, were his words  - *anagram*

Comment: This also fits "shout is what he didnt".

Answer (score 5):

### Partial Answers

#### 5. REBUS

The answer is

> ROULETTE

Because

> The first coin image is a Russia **Rouble**, 1897 (https://www.ebay.com/p/Russia-Rouble-1897/102007623).
>
>  ROUBLE - B + TM - M + TEN - N = ROULE + T + TE = **ROULETTE**

#### 3. WORDSEARCH(Or is it to search for something else?)

This is only partial, maybe it will help the others.

> There are many countries in the grid (+ Tibet?)
>
>  [image: image by athin]
>
>  Is this... lost?

Comment: Also a 4-letter / starting at G6, a 5-letter \ starting at J3, and another 5-letter \ starting at B10.